# Read operation on a views is faster or on table?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

We use views to represent data from different tables in one row and available faster for read operation.

What if the views is just a copy of a table ?
what will be faster read operation on that table or read operation on the view of that table?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Views are not (in general) "copies" of tables.  Views are definitions of queries that are substituted into other queries.

There is an exception to this rule:  materialized views which some databases (such as Oracle) support but not all.

For fastest access, you should in general go to the tables directly and set up the tables to optimize your query -- this usually involves creating indexes and sometimes vertical partitions.  Views are a great convenience and useful.  Their performance often equals that of direct access to queries.  But, with the exception of materialized views, they do not offer performance advantages.

Comment: i just saw this particular case where this person created view which is exact copy of the table and then perform complex read query  on this views(basically copy of tables) and populate result into a resulting table. So i was wondering why one would do that when you can do the same thing on the table seemed unnecessary.

Comment: @RaviJadhav . . . There are good reasons to create views, but performance is not one of them.  One key reason is to allow users to have a consistent "view" of the table, so the underlying table structure can be changed.